# Не могу понять, как заранее понять, какова будет размер массива?

Tags: c, массивы

Я писал "шифровальщик". Программа простая: пользователь пишет текст, а программа переводит его в ASCII код.

Но тут вопрос: как узнать, сколько он будет вводить и как задать размер массива в ходе выполнения программы?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char text; //вот тут problem

    printf("Введите текст: ");
    scanf("%s",text);

    for (int i=0;i<=sizeof(text);i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",text[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какое шифрование? Может считывать кусками фиксированного размера, и ими же выводить?

Comment: Для ввода по строкам можно использовать функцию [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: Что-то не очень понятно что вы хотите. Вы объявили один символ, а не массив. Вы хотите как-то предугадать, какую размерность объявлять? Почему нельзя объявить указатель `char *text`? Тогда он будет динамическим и всё бодро заработает. Ладно, может и не совсем бодро, в текущем состоянии вывалится в *segmentation fault*. Ввод можно читать построчно `scanf("%m[^\n]", &text);` либо же через *getline* как предложил @avp. Ну и при работе с указателем надо не забыть память освободить в конце работы с массивом `free(text)`.